# Bitwise Operations on style (textview typeface)

Tags: java, android, textview, typeface

I wrote code that set/unset bold and italic style to textview.
And it works perfect, but my Android Studio have a little trouble with it.

`style &= (int) ~Typeface.BOLD;` - Android Studio tells me, that casting to (int) is redundant, but when I delete it, then it shows that flag is not allowed there. This has no impact on the operation of the program - it works anyway.

So the questions are:

1. Why Android Studio tells me that casting is redundant, but when I delete it then tells that flag isn't allowed here?
2. Is my code a correct way of changing italic/bold style in textview?

Fragment of my class:

```
Textview textview = findViewById(R.id.tv1)

CheckBox bold = findViewById(R.id.checkBoxBold);
        bold.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            Typeface typeface = textview.getTypeface();
            int style = typeface.getStyle();
            if (isChecked) style |= Typeface.BOLD;
            else style &= (int) ~Typeface.BOLD;

            Typeface newTypeface = Typeface.create(textview.getTypeface(), style);
            textview.setTypeface(newTypeface);
        });
        CheckBox cursive = findViewById(R.id.checkBoxCursive);
        cursive.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            Typeface typeface = textview.getTypeface();
            int style = typeface.getStyle();

            if (isChecked) style |= Typeface.ITALIC;
            else style &= (int) ~Typeface.ITALIC;

            Typeface newTypeface = Typeface.create(textview.getTypeface(), style);
            textview.setTypeface(newTypeface);
        });
```

I've seen people make just if statements for all cases, but I'm not sure about that method.

Answer (score 0):

So you are having problems with setting typeface to your edittext/textview programmatically.

To your first question - TypeFace.Bold or TypeFace.Italic returns an Integer whereas edittext or textview needs Typeface.[image: You can see that it returns Integer]

Second the correct or the easiest way to set typeface to a view is as follows :

```
            Typeface typeface = textview.getTypeface();
            int style = typeface.getStyle();

            if (isChecked) style |= Typeface.ITALIC;
            textview.setTypeface(null,Typeface.ITALIC);
```

You can do the same for all typefaces. I hope this helps you. Do let me know if this doesn't help. I would be happy to help.